SQLModel - Update List Column Doesn't work
For some strange reason, I can't get append to work when updating SQLModel with the List column. I spend too much time trying different things and Google, and I can't get it to work.
I am using SQLModel, SQLAlchemy and Postgres
Table (I tried different configurations)
class TestList(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: int = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    texts: Optional[List[str]] = Field(default=None, sa_column=Column(ARRAY(String)))
    texts2: List[str] = Field(default=[], sa_column=Column(ARRAY(String)))
    json1: Optional[List[str]] = Field(default=[], sa_column=Column(JSON))

    # Needed for Column(JSON)
    class Config:
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True

Test code:
## Create the instance data and insert to DB.
with Session(engine) as session:
    try:
        test_list = TestList(texts=["one", "two", "three"], texts2=["four", "five", "six"], json1=["value1", "value2", "value3"])
        session.add(test_list)
        session.commit()
        session.refresh(test_list)
    except exc.SQLAlchemyError as e:
        print(e)

## Update the list. I am using a different session because in real life the update will 
## be down by different session
with Session(engine) as session:
    try:
        session.add(test_list)
        test_list.texts.append("seven")
        test_list.texts2.append("eleven")
        test_list.json1.append("value4")
        session.commit()
        session.refresh(test_list)
    except exc.SQLAlchemyError as e:
        print(e)


for ts in test_list.texts:
    print(ts)

for ts in test_list.texts2:
    print(ts)

for ts in test_list.json1:
    print(ts)


Results, as you can see the new data wasn't inserted into the DB :(
one
two
three
four
four
five
six
value1
value2
value3

I hope there is an obvious easy solution, that I am missing.

same issue here :( Any updates on this matter?

@GarbusUchiha, I ended up storing the JSON as a string in the DB and serializing and unserializing it in the Python code.  Not ideal, but worked for my use case.

As stated in sqlalchemy documentation are immutable, i.e. don't allow .append(), .remove() and other methods. Here is the example from the documentation on how to make arrays mutable:
from sqlalchemy import ARRAY
from sqlalchemy.ext.mutable import MutableList

class SomeOrmClass(Base):
    # ...

    data = Column(MutableList.as_mutable(ARRAY(Integer)))


This extension will allow “in-place” changes such to the array such as .append() to produce events which will be detected by the unit of work. Note that changes to elements inside the array, including subarrays that are mutated in place, are not detected.


The following worked for me,
import copy
...
...
lst = copy.deepcopy(test_list.list1)
lst.append("7")
test_list.list1 = lst
session.add(test_list)
session.commit(test_list)


ORM will not update changes made to database until the id connected to the object is changed. That's what deepcopy does, it created a new object with a new id, this instructs the ORM to make updates to the database.


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
